# Unhandled System.ArgumentException.. Additional Information: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, argumentexception

I have this code in c# that pulls images from database and shows them in PictureBox. Whenever I run code first, I get this error saying "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll Additional information: Parameter is not valid." But if I terminate and rerun the program, it works just fine giving intended results. Here is part of the code that is giving me trouble:

```
 private void buttonGetImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string baseUrl = "http://someurl";
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
        {
            string url = string.Format(baseUrl, fileName);
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;
            DialogResult result;
            result = MessageBox.Show(url, fileName, buttons);

            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                this.Close();
            }

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.CookieContainer = container;

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000000];
            int read, total = 0;

            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, total, 1000)) != 0)
            {
                total += read;
            }
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, total);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Current);
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
            pictureBoxTabTwo.Image = bmp;
            this.pictureBoxTabTwo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBoxTabTwo.Image.Save("FormTwo.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me to figure out what can be done?
Error is showing me line --> Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);

Comment: test for your total being zero before you pass to MemoryStream (ms). see if that gets you closer to a solution.

Comment: where is this code in your application?

Comment: @RadioSpace no its not when exception throws up.. in other cases it is.. anyway i can fix this?

Comment: I just think sometimes you are creating a zero sized memorystream and tring to use it. can you rule this out.

Comment: like using if (ms.length == 0) ?

Comment: maybe. but you should check the latest answer as well, cause it looks like there may be something to it. but it seems like it should correct an issue if your program hiccupped after first run not during it like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Bitmap class I used Image class in my program. What I was doing here was taking a stream and putting it into a byte array. And again converting content of that array back to stream. Instead, I used

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream)
```

In this case You don't even have to use MemoryStream. It is working perfectly find for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your code what the problem could be, but likely the query you are making on the server returns an unexpected response in some circumstances. You'd be best to get a snapshot of the returned stream when things goes wrong. It will allow you to diagnose the problem and take appropriate measures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do proper object disposal. Otherwise, the underlying connection doesn't close until the garbage collector catches up with the object and that can cause problems. Also, in .NET 4.0 and higher you can use the CopyTo method on Streams.

```
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.CookieContainer = container;

        using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // All of this code is unnecessary if using .NET 4.0 or higher.
            /*
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000000];
            int read, total = 0;

            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, total, 1000)) != 0)
            {
                total += read;
            }
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, total);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Current);
            */
            // Instead use the following
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(ms);

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
            pictureBoxTabTwo.Image = bmp;
            this.pictureBoxTabTwo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBoxTabTwo.Image.Save("FormTwo.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

Comment: proper disposal would be an issue on second run not first right?

Comment: Supposedly, exception is getting thrown at this line " Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);"

Comment: In the code above, How 'ms' and 'stream' are interacting with each other? And if not, how response string is passed to code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap);
```